# How can i store strings from txt.file to struct in C?

Tags: c

I have a homework due to next Monday, I need someone to guide me on how to do the next step cause I am stuck at this moment.

Here is the assignment

This assignment is based on a file with the results from the first 26 rounds of the Danish super league from 2019-2020. The name of your input file should be matches-2019-2020.txt. Each line in the file is a match result, for example
Fri 12/0719.00 FCM - EFB 1 - 0 7310
This line means that FCM (FC Midtjylland) has played at home against EFB (Esbjerg FB) on Friday 12 July at 19.00, match was watched by 7310 spectators, FCM scored a goal and EFB did not score in the match.

In the  task, all matches must be loaded into an array of structs (the match array). )u want, you can assume that there are exactly 182 matches in the tournament.

struct must store information about the match's day of the week, date (without year), the two teams, the match's result and spectator numbers.

task now is to go through all the match results in order to make an array of teams (the team array), re a team is a struct. The team struct must contain team name, points, number of goals scored by the team and number of goals scored against team. If you wish, you can assume that there are exactly 14 teams playing in the tournament.
team array can be perceived as an associative array that associates the team name with a team struct, therefore parts of the task of associative arrays can be used in this task. If you wish, you can place the teams in fixed, pre-programmed places in the team array.

The team array must now be sorted so that we can find the position in the tournament after 26 rounds. In this task, it is sorted primarily by points and secondarily by goal difference. A won match gives 3 points, a draw gives 1 point and a lost match gives no points. Print the tournament standings on standard output with one line per team in the following format:

Team name Point Goal-by-team Goal-aginst-team le. FCM 65 80 30 means Team midtjyland earns 65 points, score 80 goal and concede 30 goals
Make an effort to print the position nicely, with four equally wide columns indented in a natural and clear way.

Here is the text file

```
Fre     12/07 19.00     FCM - EFB     1 - 0     7310   
Son     14/07 12.00     SDR - RFC     2 - 1     4734   
Son     14/07 14.00     ACH - FCN     0 - 3     1653   
Son     14/07 14.00     LBK - AaB     2 - 0     2971   
Son     14/07 16.00     OB - FCK      2 - 3     9067   
Son     14/07 18.00     BIF - SIF     3 - 0     13056  
Man     15/07 19.00     HOB - AGF     1 - 1     4236   
Fre     19/07 19.00     FCK - AGF     2 - 1     15957  
Son     21/07 12.00     SIF - ACH     0 - 3     3535   
Son     21/07 14.00     AaB - SDR     1 - 1     4355   
Son     21/07 14.00     EFB - HOB     1 - 1     4452   
Son     21/07 16.00     RFC - BIF     2 - 2     5984   
Son     21/07 18.00     FCM - FCN     2 - 1     6142   
Man     22/07 19.00     OB - LBK      4 - 1     6339   
Fre     26/07 19.00     LBK - SDR     0 - 3     3168   
Lor     27/07 17.30     ACH - FCK     0 - 2     3565   
Son     28/07 12.00     HOB - RFC     2 - 2     2812   
Son     28/07 14.00     FCN - EFB     2 - 0     1982   
Son     28/07 16.00     AGF - FCM     0 - 1     11739  
Son     28/07 18.00     BIF - OB      3 - 2     13689  
Man     29/07 19.00     AaB - SIF     3 - 1     5885   
Fre     02/08 19.00     SIF - HOB     2 - 3     3468   
Lor     03/08 16.00     SDR - FCK     1 - 2     7417   
Son     04/08 12.00     RFC - FCN     3 - 1     3111   
Son     04/08 14.00     EFB - OB      0 - 1     4454   
Son     04/08 16.00     BIF - ACH     1 - 2     15148  
Son     04/08 18.00     FCM - AaB     1 - 0     7965   
Man     05/08 19.00     LBK - AGF     2 - 1     5475   
Fre     09/08 18.00     FCK - LBK     2 - 0     15747  
Fre     09/08 20.00     OB - RFC      1 - 0     6978   
Son     11/08 12.00     FCN - SIF     2 - 2     2038   
Son     11/08 14.00     AaB - EFB     4 - 0     4380   
Son     11/08 16.00     ACH - FCM     0 - 2     3179   
Son     11/08 18.00     HOB - BIF     0 - 2     4186   
Man     12/08 19.00     SDR - AGF     0 - 0     5160   
Fre     16/08 18.00     RFC - FCK     0 - 1     5118   
Fre     16/08 20.00     FCN - OB      2 - 0     2107   
Son     18/08 12.00     SIF - SDR     3 - 3     3277   
Son     18/08 14.00     EFB - LBK     1 - 0     3396   
Son     18/08 16.00     FCM - HOB     1 - 1     6978   
Son     18/08 18.00     BIF - AaB     2 - 1     11349  
Man     19/08 19.00     AGF - ACH     2 - 0     7162   
Fre     23/08 19.00     HOB - OB      0 - 0     2274   
Son     25/08 12.00     LBK - RFC     2 - 0     3226   
Son     25/08 14.00     EFB - SIF     2 - 2     3844   
Son     25/08 16.00     SDR - FCM     0 - 2     5073   
Son     25/08 18.00     BIF - AGF     0 - 3     14145  
Son     25/08 20.00     FCK - FCN     3 - 1     11316  
Man     26/08 19.00     ACH - AaB     0 - 5     2709   
Fre     30/08 19.00     OB - SDR      0 - 0     7337   
Lor     31/08 16.00     FCN - HOB     2 - 1     2529   
Son     01/09 12.00     AGF - EFB     1 - 0     10420  
Son     01/09 14.00     RFC - SIF     2 - 0     4021   
Son     01/09 14.00     ACH - LBK     2 - 1     1234   
Son     01/09 16.00     AaB - FCK     1 - 0     11645  
Son     01/09 18.00     FCM - BIF     1 - 0     10944  
Fre     13/09 19.00     SDR - ACH     0 - 0     4743   
Son     15/09 12.00     AGF - AaB     3 - 0     10235  
Son     15/09 14.00     EFB - RFC     0 - 3     3422   
Son     15/09 14.00     LBK - FCM     0 - 3     4139   
Son     15/09 16.00     HOB - FCK     2 - 1     5428   
Son     15/09 18.00     BIF - FCN     4 - 2     14648  
Man     16/09 19.00     SIF - OB      0 - 3     3502   
Fre     20/09 19.00     OB - AGF      1 - 2     10441  
Son     22/09 12.00     HOB - SDR     1 - 1     2453   
Son     22/09 14.00     FCN - AaB     2 - 1     3031   
Son     22/09 14.00     SIF - LBK     2 - 3     2452   
Son     22/09 16.00     EFB - BIF     3 - 1     5907   
Son     22/09 18.00     FCK - FCM     0 - 0     24464  
Man     23/09 19.00     RFC - ACH     2 - 1     3379   
Fre     27/09 19.00     LBK - HOB     2 - 1     3093   
Lor     28/09 17.00     FCK - SIF     4 - 2     18393  
Son     29/09 12.00     AGF - FCN     3 - 1     9149   
Son     29/09 14.00     AaB - RFC     0 - 3     5083   
Son     29/09 16.00     FCM - OB      0 - 1     8618   
Son     29/09 18.00     SDR - BIF     2 - 1     6067   
Man     30/09 19.00     ACH - EFB     1 - 1     1954   
Fre     04/10 19.00     FCN - LBK     1 - 1     3090   
Lor     05/10 16.00     HOB - AaB     0 - 2     2734   
Son     06/10 12.00     EFB - SDR     1 - 2     3718   
Son     06/10 14.00     BIF - FCK     3 - 1     21746  
Son     06/10 14.00     OB - ACH      3 - 0     6442   
Son     06/10 16.00     RFC - AGF     2 - 0     9947   
Son     06/10 18.00     SIF - FCM     1 - 2     4773   
Fre     18/10 19.00     AaB - OB      1 - 0     6086   
Son     20/10 12.00     ACH - HOB     1 - 0     2241   
Son     20/10 14.00     SDR - FCN     1 - 4     4863   
Son     20/10 14.00     AGF - SIF     3 - 4     22175  
Son     20/10 16.00     FCK - EFB     3 - 1     13872  
Son     20/10 18.00     LBK - BIF     0 - 3     8547   
Man     21/10 19.00     FCM - RFC     2 - 1     7410   
Fre     25/10 19.00     EFB - FCM     1 - 2     4637   
Son     27/10 12.00     HOB - SIF     1 - 1     1970   
Son     27/10 14.00     OB - FCN      3 - 1     5915   
Son     27/10 14.00     LBK - ACH     2 - 1     2947   
Son     27/10 16.00     BIF - RFC     5 - 2     17558  
Son     27/10 18.00     SDR - AaB     1 - 3     3843   
Man     28/10 19.00     AGF - FCK     1 - 2     13884  
Fre     01/11 19.00     EFB - ACH     1 - 1     3164   
Son     03/11 12.00     RFC - LBK     2 - 1     2909   
Son     03/11 14.00     OB - HOB      2 - 1     6237   
Son     03/11 14.00     FCN - AGF     0 - 1     3230   
Son     03/11 16.00     AaB - FCM     0 - 1     6305   
Son     03/11 18.00     FCK - SDR     3 - 0     11394  
Man     04/11 19.00     SIF - BIF     0 - 1     5432   
Fre     08/11 19.00     RFC - AaB     3 - 3     4156   
Lor     09/11 16.00     ACH - SIF     2 - 1     1826   
Son     10/11 12.00     HOB - FCN     2 - 2     1733   
Son     10/11 14.00     AGF - SDR     4 - 2     6291   
Son     10/11 14.00     LBK - OB      4 - 3     4046   
Son     10/11 16.00     BIF - EFB     2 - 1     12392  
Son     10/11 18.00     FCM - FCK     4 - 1     11422  
Fre     22/11 19.00     FCN - RFC     3 - 0     1441   
Son     24/11 12.00     SDR - LBK     2 - 2     3712   
Son     24/11 14.00     AaB - ACH     4 - 0     4048   
Son     24/11 14.00     SIF - EFB     1 - 2     2876   
Son     24/11 16.00     FCK - HOB     2 - 1     11512  
Son     24/11 18.00     AGF - BIF     2 - 1     14043  
Man     25/11 19.00     OB - FCM      1 - 2     6392   
Fre     29/11 19.00     LBK - FCN     1 - 1     4419   
Son     01/12 11.45     FCK - BIF     2 - 1     29310  
Son     01/12 12.00     RFC - SDR     3 - 0     2057   
Son     01/12 14.00     ACH - OB      2 - 1     1690   
Son     01/12 16.00     EFB - AGF     1 - 2     4608   
Son     01/12 18.00     AaB - HOB     1 - 1     4520   
Man     02/12 19.00     FCM - SIF     2 - 1     6612   
Fre     06/12 19.00     HOB - ACH     0 - 0     1356   
Son     08/12 12.00     SIF - RFC     2 - 1     1984   
Son     08/12 14.00     SDR - EFB     2 - 1     3623   
Son     08/12 14.00     AGF - LBK     1 - 1     6138   
Son     08/12 16.00     FCN - FCK     0 - 1     5133   
Son     08/12 18.00     BIF - FCM     1 - 2     13317  
Man     09/12 19.00     OB - AaB      0 - 0     5801   
Fre     13/12 19.00     AaB - FCN     1 - 3     3791   
Son     15/12 12.00     ACH - SDR     2 - 1     1261   
Son     15/12 14.00     RFC - EFB     3 - 0     2103   
Son     15/12 14.00     LBK - SIF     1 - 0     2434   
Son     15/12 16.00     BIF - HOB     1 - 1     9703   
Son     15/12 18.00     FCM - AGF     1 - 3     11009
Man     16/12 19.00     FCK - OB      2 - 1     12226
Fre     14/02 19.00     EFB - FCK     1 - 0     5449   
Son     16/02 12.00     SDR - HOB     3 - 1     4316   
Son     16/02 14.00     SIF - AaB     0 - 2     2667   
Son     16/02 18.00     OB - BIF      0 - 2     9576   
Man     17/02 19.00     FCM - LBK     2 - 0     6108
Ons     19/02 18.30     FCN - ACH     6 - 0     1621   
Tor     28/05 19.00     AGF - RFC     1 - 1     0       
Fre     21/02 19.00     HOB - FCM     0 - 2     2071   
Son     23/02 12.00     FCN - SDR     2 - 1     1552   
Son     23/02 14.00     RFC - OB      0 - 0     3103   
Son     23/02 14.00     LBK - EFB     2 - 0     3114   
Son     23/02 16.00     SIF - FCK     1 - 1     3282   
Son     23/02 18.00     AaB - BIF     3 - 2     7896   
Man     24/02 19.00     ACH - AGF     1 - 2     3566   
Fre     28/02 19.00     AGF - HOB     0 - 0     7530   
Lor     29/02 16.00     EFB - FCN     1 - 2     3116   
Son     01/03 12.00     ACH - RFC     1 - 2     1794   
Son     01/03 14.00     OB - SIF      1 - 1     4864   
Son     01/03 16.00     BIF - LBK     1 - 0     16388  
Son     01/03 18.00     FCK - AaB     3 - 2     13240  
Man     02/03 19.00     FCM - SDR     3 - 0     8103   
Son     08/03 12.00     HOB - EFB     1 - 1     0       
Son     08/03 14.00     SDR - OB      1 - 1     0       
Son     08/03 14.00     AaB - LBK     3 - 0     0       
Son     08/03 16.00     FCK - ACH     0 - 1     0       
Son     08/03 18.00     FCN - BIF     2 - 2     0       
Son     08/03 20.00     RFC - FCM     0 - 2     0       
Man     09/03 19.00     SIF - AGF     2 - 1     0       
Fre     29/05 19.00     SIF - FCN     0 - 2     0       
Son     31/05 18.00     EFB - AaB     1 - 1     0       
Man     01/06 14.00     RFC - HOB     0 - 1     0       
Man     01/06 16.00     FCM - ACH     0 - 1     0       
Man     01/06 18.00     LBK - FCK     1 - 4     0       
Man     01/06 20.00     AGF - OB      1 - 0     0       
Tir     02/06 19.00     BIF - SDR     1 - 0     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     FCK - RFC     2 - 1     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     SDR - SIF     2 - 2     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     AaB - AGF     2 - 3     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     OB - EFB      3 - 1     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     ACH - BIF     3 - 2     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     FCN - FCM     0 - 1     0       
Son     07/06 17.00     HOB - LBK     2 - 2     0
```

This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMOFTEAMS 14
typedef struct match
{
    char day_name[4];
    int day;
    int month;
    float hour;
    char team_1[4];
    char team_2[4];
    int team_1_goal;
    int team_2_goal;
    int viewer;
} match;

typedef struct team
{
    char* team_names;
    int goals_scored;
    int goal_conceded;
    int points;

} team;


int
 main()
{
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("kampe-2019-2020.txt", "r");
char str[255];

while(fgets(str, 255, fp) != NULL) {
printf("%s", str);
}
if(fp == NULL){
printf("File not found...\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}}
```

So I have created 2 struct and fopen to open the text file and print it.
my questions are

1. when i open the file with fopen and fget, how can i store the information to struct team and struct match?
2. After I have done that how can I write a function to sort team array as the assignment mention?

I would appreciate if someone can help me on Discord since I am quite new to C and the assignment is too hard for me

Comment: The whole text file is overkill. 5 lines of it is more than enough to show what your data looks like.

Comment: Are you aware of `sscanf()` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of arrays of structs?

Comment: Do the check of `fopen()` failure BEFORE you rely on it having succeeded.

Comment: The shown code is a standard "read and display" program. It does not even attempt to do anything as mentioned in your assignment. This lacks focus on what obstacle you encountered while seriously trying yourself.

Comment: @Yunnosch: wouldnt fgets also fail with no file open?

Comment: @WolfgangRoth You seem to agree with me... I think I miss your point.

Comment: @Yunnosch, my point is, that fgets could get also a NULL ptr if the file is not already open...ß

Comment: @WolfgangRoth Ah I see. You mean the fgets loop ends and then the if gives an explanation. Yes, true. But the if-check first would be a protection for all of the rest of the program which OPs is trying/going to implement.

Comment: @Yunnosch, exactly what i am thinking. Code does not malbehave this way, but the other way round it would be more safe - espec. when the fgets implementation gets changed and would throw an exception instead of returning NULL

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP literally expects us to do their work for them and/or tutor them.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I store the information to struct team and struct match?

The are multiple options, but consider:

1. Using the [`sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function on the line you read into `str`.
2. Instead of `fgets()`'ing, use [`fscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) on the input file directly to scan from it.

You will need to pass the addresses of the fields of your struct to those functions.

> how can I write a function to sort team array as the assignment mention?

I won't do your homework for you, but - think about how you would do this *by hand*. Forget about programming C. I'm giving you the table of match results and you need to sum up the information into a table of team statistics. How would you do it - without a computer? ... Now try to do that, but in C.

Comment: I still don't get it, do you have discord or something? you can tutor me cause i am dumb with progrmaming for now

Comment: Please contact your teaching staff for help with your homework.